# Textures getting warped close to a vertex

Tags: uv

I am trying to do a simple pixel art style model, but when I try to texture this part, the pixels get warped...it seems that the door section in the texture is causing the warping. Can someone tell me how to fix it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

N-gons can give unreliable texturing results in some cases. Add a triangulation modifier to the stack or triangulate the face.